# Disable push notification when user logged out when using MC SDK 8.x

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, ios

I found the answer for 7.x versions of sdk how to disable push notifications. Its a simple call `sfmc_setPushEnabled(Bool)`. But I have migrated to 8.x spms, i couldnt find a equivalent to `sfmc_setPushEnabled(Bool)`. Please help me how to stop push when user logs out.

I tried clearing attributes also.

```
SFMCSdk.identity.setProfileId([ModuleName.push: "NoPush"])
SFMCSdk.identity.setProfileAttributes([ModuleName.push: [["firstname": "","lastname":"","subscriberId":""]]])
SFMCSdk.identity.PushEnabled(false)---------> Should i put anything like this ??
```

Comment: There is no user logged in/logged out state in the SDK. That is an application feature/implementation. Your question should simply be: how do I disable push in SDK v8.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding logged in/logged out state: as Bill mentioned in the comment, that is an application feature/implementation.

In v8.x, you can access the MobilePush module using `SFMCSdk.mp`

To disable push in SDK v8.x (i.e. like in v7.x `sfmc_setPushEnabled(Bool)`) you can use the following:

`SFMCSdk.mp.setPushEnabled(false)`

Comment: I added the code above mentioned when a user logs out. But still if create a message -> filter by my contact list -> Send the push message. The push message is still receiving. After adding the above code, should i do anything further to stop push from MarketingCloud SDK.

Comment: Should i clear the profile attributes with it. ??